# Why does as the JPanel class object be created, the paintComponent method is automatically called?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, repaint, paintcomponent

This is the java code about `JPanel`:

```
class Battle_field extends JPanel{
    public List<Image_Obj> pics_to_be_drawn;    

    @Override   
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){     
            super.paintComponent(g);                 
            g.drawImage(pics_to_be_drawn.get(0).Get_the_buf_img() , 41, 41, 59, 59, Color.black, null);
    }       
}
```

As I set up the GUI:

```
added_panel= new Battle_field();
added_panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(SystemColor.activeCaption, 3));
added_panel.setBounds(27, 10, 397, 630);
added_panel.setBackground(Color.white);
this.getContentPane().add(added_panel);
```

I found that the creation of `Battle_field()` object above will call the `paintComponent` automatically.

> But here, I didn't initialize the variable **"pics_to_be_drawn"** yet,so if it is called, it would cause compiler error. **Is this design unavoidable?** 
>   
> As you do so, it's necessary to happen?
>   I wanna know this very much and of course the solution.

p.s:
According to the official document,only if I call `repaint()`, it will call `paintComponent()`. So I can write my customized code within `paintComponent`.

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: @kleopatra What do you mean? Please take for example. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing calls the `paintComponent()` method when the panel must be painted. I don't think it will call it until the panel is made visible.

That said, your panel should be in a paintable state as soon as it's added to the GUI. So the `paintComponent()` method should handle the case where the pictures have not been added yet, by simply checking that the list if not null (and not empty):

```
@Override   
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){     
    super.paintComponent(g);                 
    if (pics_to_be_drawn != null && !pics_to_be_drawn.isEmpty()) {
        g.drawImage(pics_to_be_drawn.get(0).Get_the_buf_img() , 41, 41, 59, 59, Color.black, null);
    }
}
```

Side note: I would initialize the list to `Collections.emptyList()` or to `new ArrayList<>()`, which would avoid the check for null. I would also respect the Java naming conventions: no underscore in class and variable names, camelCasing.

Comment: Good idea to be sure that it's not empty first. I forgot that. 1+

Comment: Oh, my god, you response the answer so quick and correct. Thank u so 
much JB!

Answer (score 2):

Realize that you do not have control over when or if `paint(...)` or `paintComponent(...)` are called, that `repaint()` only suggests the repaint manager that the component should be painted, but that this doesn't always happen, that painting will occur as soon as the component is *rendered*, and then accept this and gear your code to work around this. Consider:

- Initialize pics_to_be_drawn to null (so you initialize it to something)
- Then check that it's not null before drawing it.

Change this:

```
class Battle_field extends JPanel{
    public List<Image_Obj> pics_to_be_drawn;    

    @Override   
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){     
            super.paintComponent(g);                 
            g.drawImage(pics_to_be_drawn.get(0).Get_the_buf_img() , 41, 41, 59, 59, Color.black, null);
    }       
}
```

to this:

```
class Battle_field extends JPanel{
    public List<Image_Obj> pics_to_be_drawn;    

    @Override   
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){     
            super.paintComponent(g);          
            if (pics_to_be_drawn != null) { 
               g.drawImage(pics_to_be_drawn.get(0).Get_the_buf_img() , 41, 41, 59, 59, Color.black, null);
            }
    }       
}
```

Simple

Comment: Why are you guys can answer the question so quick. Amazing...
You both are great! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Jpanel's paintComponent is automatically called when a window becomes visible (uncovered or deminimized) or is resized. [Here's some more info about when paintComponent can be called.](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI-lowlevel/graphics/15who-calls-paintcomponent.html)